# Triggering events with Javascript inside google captcha box doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, captcha

I am trying to use `querySelector` to select an element within the google captcha box but it seems to just fire but ignore it.

```
const elm = document.querySelector('.rc-button.goog-inline-block');
elm.click();
```

Comment: Firstly, if I recall correctly, the Google Captcha runs in an iframe, so you cannot amend it via JS as it's cross-domain. Secondly, it sounds like you're trying to programmatically work around the CAPTCHA, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: It's for an automated test